C++ VCPKG Install external library
I'm stuck with installing tinyxml2 to using vcpkg and link it using CMake
The following steps were taken

Install vcpkg
Run vcpkg add port tinyxml2
Run vcpkg to install tinyxml2
Run vcpkg integrate install

For CMake I have the following 2 files
CMakeLists.txt

project(HelloWorld)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "./vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" CACHE STRING "Vcpkg toolchain file")

find_package(tinyxml2 CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(HelloWorld main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(HelloWorld PRIVATE tinyxml2::tinyxml2)


CMakePresets.json
{
    "version": 2,
    "configurePresets": [
      {
        "name": "default",
        "generator": "Ninja",
        "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build",
        "cacheVariables": {
          "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "./vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
        }
      }
    ]
  }

Now I'm running  cmake --preset=default and afterwards  cmake --build build
This results in the following error
[1/1] Linking CXX executable HelloWorld.exe
FAILED: HelloWorld.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\c++.exe   CMakeFiles/HelloWorld.dir/main.cpp.obj 
-o HelloWorld.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libHelloWorld.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/tinyxml2.lib  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\Users\<user>\dev\cpp\playground\build && C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass -file 
C:/Users/<user>/dev/cpp/playground/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/msbuild/applocal.ps1 -targetBinary C:/Users/<user>/dev/cpp/playground/build/HelloWorld.exe -installedDir C:/Users/<user>/dev/cpp/playground/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/bin -OutVariable out""
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/HelloWorld.dir/main.cpp.obj:main.cpp:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN8tinyxml211XMLDocumentC1EbNS_10WhitespaceE'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/HelloWorld.dir/main.cpp.obj:main.cpp:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN8tinyxml211XMLDocumentD1Ev'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/HelloWorld.dir/main.cpp.obj:main.cpp:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN8tinyxml211XMLDocumentD1Ev'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

My main.cpp file
#include <iostream>
#include <tinyxml2.h>

using namespace tinyxml2;

int main() {

   XMLDocument doc;
   
   std::cout << "Hello";

}

Where did I go wrong when trying to add tinyxml2 via vcpkg?
I even see the header file in vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\tinyxml2.h
Thanks for any tips

vcpkg\installed\x64-windows is for msvc and not compatible with MinGW for c++ based libraries. If you want to use vcpkg for MinGW you need to use a MinGW triplet for building the vcpkg packages.

Your compile for GCC ABI, but you have installed the incompatible MSVC library. You should use MSYS2 pacman instead of vcpkg
pacman -S tinyxml2

Remove "cacheVariables" from the preset file.

Note that set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE has no affect in CMakeLists.txt.

Thanks a ton. I thought vcpkg is the package maanger on windows. Shouldnt I be able to use it ?  No way getting it working wih vcpkg?

vcpkg is rather "Visual C package manager". Use MS Visual Studio on Windows. There is no a value of using GCC on Windows. Once you have chosen MSYS2, use pacman.

vcpkg does have a mingw triplet, and the package is listed as supported on all triplets, i think you just need to follow vcpkg MSDN mingw docs

I thought vcpkg is the package maanger on windows. The default triplets in vcpkg on windows build for msvc and not MinGW. These 2 different compilers are not compatible for c++ based code.

I think set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE might work but it needs to be before project
